# how i can center a drawing in canvas like google maps

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hi i am working on an application of maps, i have a form which permit to register the coordinates like dd/mm/ss O and dd/mm/ss N , with that i display a point in my maps but i wish to display a point in canvas middle like google maps display user position in center of screen
i had try with

```js
ctx.translate(x,y)
```

where i convert dd/mm/ss O to pixels on axis X and dd/mm/ss N on axis Y

excuse for my bad english
I put my hope to u to live in this case

Comment: *I think you want* to cause an [x,y] on your map to draw at center canvas. If you want to pull any [x,y] to the center of the canvas you can do it like this: `translate( canvas.width/2-x, canvas.height/2-y )` and then `drawImage(map,0,0)`.

Comment: Hi i think it possible to move the map image to put the drawing in the center of canvas but i dont know it can do .Please if someone can help me to find the solution thank

Comment: i can move the image(map) where i wan with drawImage(img,pointX,pointY) but i want to display the point on the middle of canvas. please i need  your help